# Passing function in other functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, function

I've recently started studying programming and JS, HTML, CSS.
Reading a book at the moment which includes the following snippet of code which i try to understand and modify for my own practice and attempts in understanding. But i really can't grasp what's going on.
Is there anyone that could please try and explain what's happening and why my modified snippet of code won't run - as it does look similar to part of the original one that does run fine.
First snippet attached is original one from book.
Second is mine which is built on parts of the prior one.

```js
var validateDataForAge = function(data) {
  person = data();
  console.log(person);
  if (person.age <1 || person.age > 99){
      return true;
  } else{
      return false;
  }
};

var errorHandlerForAge = function(error) {
  console.log("Error while processing age");
};

function parseRequest(data,validateData,errorHandler) {
  var error = validateData(data);
  if (!error) {
  console.log("no errors");
  } else {
  errorHandler();
  }
}

var generateDataForScientist = function() {
  return {
    name: "Albert Einstein",
    age : Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1,
  };
};

//parse request
parseRequest(generateDataForScientist, validateDataForAge,
errorHandlerForAge);
```

```js
var validateAge = function(age) {
  person = age();
  console.log(age);

}

validateAge(17);
```

I get following errormessage:

TypeError: age is not a function
    at validateAge:2:12
    at eval:7:1
    at eval
    at new Promise

Thankful for any help.

Regards,

Comment: You need to define the age as function

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you are looking at. It expects `data` to be a function.

> ```
> var validateDataForAge = function(data) {
>   person = data();
> ```

… and so it is (the one assigned to `generateDataForScientist` after it gets passed through a couple of other variables and function calls).

---

Here is your code:

> ```
> var validateAge = function(age) {
>   person = age();
> ```

It expects `age` to be a function.

Here you pass it a value:

> ```
> validateAge(17);
> ```

`17` is a number, not a function.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in this part of your code

```
var generateDataForScientist = function() {
  return {
    name: "Albert Einstein",
    age : Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1, // <- problem
  };
};
```

age is just a property of the object your returning and you are using age as a function in this code

```
var validateAge = function(age) {
  person = age(); // <-- here ,age is not a function
  console.log(age);

}
```

you need to chage the age property to be a function like this

```
var generateDataForScientist = function() {
  return {
    name: "Albert Einstein",
    age : function (){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1 },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

consoling `data` inside `parseRequest` will log it as a function. But you need the property `age`. So replace `validateData(data)` with  `validateData(data());`

```js
var validateDataForAge = function(data) {
  let person = data;
  if (person.age < 1 || person.age > 99) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

var errorHandlerForAge = function(error) {
  console.log("Error while processing age");
};

function parseRequest(data, validateData, errorHandler) {
  console.log(data)
  var error = validateData(data());
  if (!error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    errorHandler();
  }
}

var generateDataForScientist = function() {
  return {
    name: "Albert Einstein",
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1,
  };
};

//parse request
parseRequest(generateDataForScientist, validateDataForAge, errorHandlerForAge);
```